# Wrong executing order with NodeJS callback based function in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use a callback function in a promise chain. Actually the original code is divided into two files and contains a lot more code, but to make the problem clear I've simplified it into one simple file.

I'm expecting the following code to produce: A B C D E F, but instead I get: A D B E C F. I can't understand why D gets called before B, and how to make the code work as expected!

When I'm not calling any callback based function and just use Q.async functions then it is working as expected!

Here is the code:

```
var Q = require('q');
var FlakeId = require('flake-idgen');
var biguint = require('biguint-format');
var flakeIdGen = new FlakeId({ id: 0, epoch: 1234567891234 });
var idDec = null;

var deferred = Q.defer();
var createId = function() {
  console.log('A');
    flakeIdGen.next(function (err, id) {
      console.log('B');
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error 1');
        deferred.reject(new Error(err));
      } else {
        idDec = biguint(id, 'dec');
        deferred.resolve(idDec);
      }   
    }); 
  return deferred.promise;
};

var doSomething = Q.async(function* () {
  console.log('D');
});

createId().then(function(idDec) {
    console.log('C');
  }).fail(function(err) {
    console.log('Error 2');
}).then(
doSomething().then(function() {
    console.log('E');
  }).fail(function(err) {
    console.log('Error 3');
}).then(function() {
  console.log('F');
  }
));
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try returning doSomething and continue the thens on the same level, assuming Q,async() returns a promise.

Comment: I think, it's because in `Node.js` events are registered asynchronously. To set specific order, define your events in callback of previous event

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But actually I have just started with promises to avoid 'callback hell' as my code then gets really 'ugly' and hard to maintain!

Answer (score 2):

the issue is how you are calling doSomething

This code should work in the order you need

```
createId()
.then(function(idDec) {
    console.log('C');
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log('Error 2');
})
.then(function() { // edited as per comments
    return doSomething(p1, p2);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('E');
}).fail(function(err) {
    console.log('Error 3');
}).then(function() {
    console.log('F');
});
```

using doSomething like `doSomething()` will execute it immediately, and the `.then(` will ignore it as it isn't a function ... `doSomething` a an argument is a function ... `doSomething()` as an argument is the result of the function

As I am not fully conversant with the semantics of the contents of `doSomething` function, the above may not actually work, I have no way to test that specific code

I assume that doSomething returns either a value or a Promise

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually your code works if I copy/paste it into the example given. But in my program I actually need to transfer several parameters to doSomething (as in doSomething(param1, param2)), and then it is not working anymore (probably for the same reason as you have explained)!

Comment: Wrap it in anonymous function and call doSomething with parameters. .. eg  return doSomething(p1,p2);